# No space left on /tmp

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, disk-usage

I am very new to Ubuntu. Whenever I try to download files (pdf attachments from an email, etc), I get an error stating that there is not enough space in /tmp. Also, my browser tabs are crashing constantly (Firefox). Not sure if these are related issues. Here is the output of `df -h`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           375M   39M  336M  11% /run
/dev/sdb5        19G   18G     0 100% /
tmpfs           1.9G   33M  1.8G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb6       892G  752M  846G   1% /home
tmpfs           375M   76K  375M   1% /run/user/1000
```

The extra partitions came from trying other posted solutions on here but nothing seems to work. I would like to get rid of the unecessary partitions as well as address the space issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You run out of space on your main disk (/dev/sdb5), indeed as you can see, `df` says:

```
/dev/sdb5      ..... 100% /
```

Well, this is a problem since `/tmp` resides on root (`/`), among other things.

I think in your case the best and easiest solution is to enlarge your root (`/`) by shrink-ing your `/home`, since it is really really big.

Comment: Thanks for the response, could you explain how I might do that?

Comment: For manage with partition there are many tools both CLI and GUI. Personally I use gparted https://gparted.org/, a graphical partition editor. The *"problem"* is that the partitions in question are mounted (in use) and this prevent you by simply use the tool. I suggest you to boot a second OS which have gparted in it, personally I use SystemRescueCD http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/: download and boot it, start the graphical environment with command `startx` and use *gparted* to resize those partitions